# Data flow insert lock

Tags: sql, ssis

I have an issue with my data flow task locking, this task compares a couple of tables, from the same server and the result is inserted into one of the tables being compared. The table being inserted into is being compared by a NOT EXISTS clause.

When performing fast load the task freezes with out errors when doing a regular insert the task gives a dead lock error.

I have 2 other tasks that perform the same action to the same table and they work fine but the amount of information being inserted is alot smaller. I am not running these tasks in parallel.

I am considering using no locks hint to get around this because this is the only task that writes to a cerain table partition, however I am only coming to this conclusion because I can not figure out anything else, aside from using a temp table, or a hashed anti join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you have so called deadlock situation. You have in your DataFlow Task (DFT) two separate connection instances to the same table. The first conn instance runs `SELECT` and places Shared lock on the table, the second runs `INSERT` and places a page or table lock.
A few words on possible cause. SSIS DFT reads table rows and processes it in batches. When number of rows is small, read is completed within a single batch, and Shared lock is eliminated when  Insert takes place. When number of rows is substantial, SSIS splits rows into several batches, and processes it consequentially. This allows to perform steps following DFT Data Source before the Data Source completes reading.
The design - reading and writing the same table in the same Data Flow is not good because of possible locking issue. Ways to work it out:

- Move all DFT logic inside single INSERT statement and get rid of DFT. Might not be possible.
- Split DFT, move data into intermediate table, and then - move to the target table with following DFT or SQL Command. Additional table needed.
- Set a Read Committed Snapshot Isolation (RCSI) on the DB and use Read Committed on SELECT. Applicable to MS SQL DB only.

The most universal way is the second with an additional table. The third is for MS SQL only.